# ggplot in R - stop error bars going below zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting the modelled population density of several bird species +/- standard error. Because the y variable is density, values of less than zero make no sense, I want to truncate the error bars so they don't go below zero. However, I'm having trouble doing this.

This code works fine, but as you can see for Black Kite the error bars go below zero:

```
bird.plot.data <- data.frame(species = rep(c("Black kite", "Cormorant","Goosander"),2),
                             Restored = c(rep("YES",3), rep("NO",3)),
                             est.count = c(1.48, 3.12, 20.0, 0, 5.18, 2.11),
                             std.err = c(1.78, 1.78, 1.39, 0, 0.66, 1.02))


bird.plot <- ggplot(data = bird.plot.data, aes(x = Restored))+
  facet_wrap(~ species, scales = "free_y")+
  geom_col(aes(y = est.count, fill = Restored), position = position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = est.count + std.err, ymin = est.count - std.err ))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "olivedrab1"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  ylab("Estimated density (birds/km\U00B2)")

last_plot()
```

I've tried a couple of options. The most obvious one would be to modify the ymin of the error bars themselves to be no lower than zero. However, this messes up the error bars completely and I'm not sure why:

```
b.p.mod <- ggplot(data = bird.plot.data, aes(x = Restored))+
      facet_wrap(~ species, scales = "free_y")+
      geom_col(aes(y = est.count, fill = Restored), position = position_dodge())+
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = est.count + std.err, ymin = max(est.count - std.err, 0)))+
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "olivedrab1"))+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_blank())+
      ylab("Estimated density (birds/km\U00B2)")

    last_plot()
```

Another option would be to limit the y axis to 0 so the error bar is not shown below zero. However, the cropping method

```
b.p.mod2 <- bird.plot + ylim(0,NA)
last_plot()
```

removes the error bar completely, which I don't want. The zooming method

```
b.p.mod3 <- bird.plot + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,NA))
last_plot() # Produces error
```

Doesn't let me leave the upper end unspecified, which is important as different species have very different densities.

Thoughts? My preferred solution would be to work out why the first option is creating such odd results.

Comment: I suspect you need to use `pmax` instead of `max` in your code. The latter will look for the maximum across the whole data while the former will do it on a case by case basis.

Comment: `geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = est.count + std.err, ymin = pmax(est.count - std.err, 0)))`

Comment: Yep, that works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but maybe somebody will stumble upon the same problem.

For me:

`geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = est.count + std.err, ymin = ifelse(est.count - std.err < 0, 0, est.count - std.err)))`

works perfectly fine :)

Comment: And someone did, thank you!